# Stream overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

why does
`void operator<<(ostream out, Test &t);`
return an error whereas 
`void operator<<(ostream &out, Test &t);`
does not ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you cannot copy streams, you have to pass them per reference.

Note that the canonical form of `operator<<` is this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Test &t)
{
   // write t into out
   return out;
}
```

returning the stream is important so that you can string output together:

```
std::cout << Test() << '\n';
```

Comment: The second argument should be `const Test& t` (outputting shouldn't modify the object).

Comment: @visitor: You're certainly right, I copied without looking closely enough. Thanks for catching this!